# Model inconsistency during activation?

Tags: hana

In SAP HANA I get the following Error during Activation:

Repository: Encountered an error in repository runtime extension;Model inconsistency. Create Scenario failed: The following errors occurred: Index does not exist;Failed to get CalcIndex '_SYS_BIC:asdf/CA_asdf_BASE (t -1)' (2007)

What could be the reasons?
Unfortunately the error message does not indicate what the problem is :/

Answer (score 1):

**One possible reason is that the underlying view(s) are not activated.**
As a  result you can not activate the view on top.

In this case the error message indicates that the underlying view (CA_asdf_BASE) is not activated.

So ensure that all underlying views are activated.

**If this does not help then try:**

1. Revert to last active version
2. Repeat the last steps.

Answer (score 0):

Also, try to draw down your data model and check if there is a recursion. Somehow that was the case in my example. I was trying to add a view A into view B, but as a matter of fact, view B had already used view A a few levels below. Logic/brain error :)